# Moving a child control to top

Tags: c++, winapi

How can i move a control to top of the other when they have overlap together in **windows API**.

For example i create 2 buttons **b1** and **b2**

```
     HWND b1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"button1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
    100, 100, 200, 50, my_Window_handle, (HMENU)100, NULL, NULL);

    HWND b2 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"button2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
    50, 100, 250, 50, my_Window_handle, (HMENU)101, NULL, NULL);
```

I want to move b1 to top of the b2 or any control. 
I used the function *SetWindowPos* as

```
SetWindowPos(b1, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

but id does not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topmost will not work here because the child window must stay at the same z-order as its parent and SetWindowPos with HWND_TOPMOST as Hwnd_InsertAfter will try to change it. Only thing you need here is **WS_CLIPSIBLINGS** and then **b1** will remain on top of **b2**.

```
 b1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"button1", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
100, 100, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)100, NULL, NULL);

 b2 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"button2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 50, 100, 250, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)101, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the child window to be top most, you want it to be at the top of the z-order. Like this:

```
SetWindowPos(b1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) says for `HWND_TOP`:

> Places the window at the top of the Z order.

Comment: Works well here. What's the difference between your code and my code?

Comment: When i move the mouse on the button 'b2' , 'b2' moves on top of the b1.

Comment: So problem is in your code, not in David's answer. When you call SetWindowPos? Sure not in WM_CREATE message handler.

Comment: I call SetWindowPos after creating the buttons.

Comment: Again, what is special about your code? Remember that we cannot see it.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly work. Afaik Z-Order of non-top-level-windows has no meaning wrt. to drawing in Win32. Which window appears "on top" depends on drawing order and clipping. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/HMd38kvVVlMQEfcb/8920d70aff2b638033ea501fdf35e7b9) demonstrating this - `F1` and `F2` to call `SetWindowPos` as you describe. `F5` to repaint everything. [See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17724475/653473)

Answer (score 1):

As well as setting the z-order, you need to set the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style on the controls if they overlap, to stop them drawing over the top of each other.

Comment: I used the **WS_CLIPSIBLINGS** style on two buttons and b1 moved on top. 
If i create b2 before b1, b2 moves on top.  
Using the function SetWindowPos i can move two buttons on top.The problem was in the style of the window. thanks Jonathan Potter.