# How to use the SetWindowPos function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'd like to create a Windows app consisting of a main parent window and several child windows. Here is an excerpt of the code I have so far:

```
...

   // -----> CHILD WINDOWS <-----

   HWND hWnd_child1 = CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"Child 1", WS_CHILD,
     0, 0, 100, 80, hParentWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd_child1) {
     MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateWindowW Child 1", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
     return FALSE;
   }

   HWND hWnd_child2 = CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"Child 2", WS_CHILD,
     10, 10, 160, 120, hParentWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd_child2) {
     MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateWindowW Child 2", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
     return FALSE;
   }

   HWND hWnd_child3 = CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"Child 3", WS_CHILD,
     20, 20, 160, 120, hParentWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd_child3) {
     MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateWindowW Child 3", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
     return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd_child3, nCmdShow);
   SetWindowPos(hWnd_child2, HWND_TOP, 10, 10, 100, 80, NULL);
   ShowWindow(hWnd_child2, nCmdShow);
   SetWindowPos(hWnd_child1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 100, 80, NULL);
   ShowWindow(hWnd_child1, nCmdShow);

   ShowWindow(hParentWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hParentWnd);

   // -------------------
...
```

The problem is with the `SetWindowPos()` function. I can't understand how it really works. I thought that calling it like this:

```
ShowWindow(hWnd_child3, nCmdShow);
SetWindowPos(hWnd_child2, HWND_TOP, 10, 10, 100, 80, NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd_child2, nCmdShow);
SetWindowPos(hWnd_child1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 100, 80, NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd_child1, nCmdShow);
```

Would move the `Child 1` window to the top of all the app windows (as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) says for the  `HWND_TOP` option: `Places the window at the top of the Z order`).

BUT, the windows are still drawned in the creation order:

[image]

Shouldn't `SetWindowPos()` move firstly `Child 2` over `Child 3`, and next `Child 1` over `Child 2`, making the windows laid up in the reverse order than they were created, with `Child 1` on top?

Comment: If everything is `HWND_TOP` then who actually has priority? 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving a child control to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861073/moving-a-child-control-to-top)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722398/child-window-z-order/17724475#17724475 (essentially the difference between z order and clip siblings)

Comment: You might need to make those child windows redraw themselves as well.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, Yes this a similar question BUT what's the most STRANGE calling the `SetWindowPos(b1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);` as David Heffernan suggested DOEN'T work for me BUT instead calling the `SetWindowPos` on the `b2` DID the work!. Is it STRANGE!?

Comment: @darek_911 the answers to those questions, and jwezorek's answer below all suggest WS_CLIPSIBLINGS to avoid that. As such it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Make the child windows all have the window style WS_CLIPSIBLINGS along with WS_CHILD etc.

From Microsoft's documentation:

> If WS_CLIPSIBLINGS is not specified and child windows overlap, it is
> possible, when drawing within the client area of a child window, to
> draw within the client area of a neighboring child window.

Basically if the child windows do not clip each other then the order in which they are painted (which is arbitrary) determines the visual z-order.

Below for instance is your code with the message box stuff removed, using WS_VISIBLE instead of ShowWindow, adding a border for visibility, and using WS_CLIPSIBLINGS.

```
BOOL CreateChildren(HWND hParentWnd) {
    HWND hWnd_child1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"STATIC", L"Child 1", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        0, 0, 100, 80, hParentWnd, nullptr, g_hInstance, nullptr);

    HWND hWnd_child2 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"STATIC", L"Child 2", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        10, 10, 160, 120, hParentWnd, nullptr, g_hInstance, nullptr);

    HWND hWnd_child3 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"STATIC", L"Child 3", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        20, 20, 160, 120, hParentWnd, nullptr, g_hInstance, nullptr);

    SetWindowPos(hWnd_child2, HWND_TOP, 10, 10, 100, 80, NULL);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd_child1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 100, 80, NULL);

    UpdateWindow(hParentWnd);
    return TRUE;
}
```

which yields
[image: overlapping children]
child1 is on top.

Comment: Ok, I know that but when I explicitly move the `Child 1` to the top of the z ordered stack by calling `SetWindowPos(hWnd_child1, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 100, 80, NULL);`  WHY doesn't it work!?

Comment: It does work. I will update my answer with a picture hold on. You need to be clear on what you expect it to look like when it is working e.g. no border around the children etc.

Comment: Ok with the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` it actually works BUT I've asked about the case WITHOUT using the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` ?

Comment: Without clip siblings child1 can be on top of the z-order but have child 2 painted over top of it if it if child 2 was painted after child 1. With clip siblings even if child 2 is painted last when it paints the area in which it will be painted is clipped such that child 1 will not be over-painted.

Comment: Just think of WS_CLIPSIBLINGS as being the default case. Not using WS_CLIPSIBLINGS is an optimization for the case in which you know the children will never overlap so you are telling Win32 to not bother with figuring out the clipping.

Comment: "Without clip siblings child1 can be on top of the z-order but have child 2 painted over top of it if it if child 2 was painted after child " - so does it mean that moving the window in the z order hierarchy DOESN't make it to be re-drawn?

Comment: Can You please respond to my last question?

Comment: @darek_911 if you don't use the `SWP_NOREDRAW` flag, every call to `SetWindowPos` will cause that window to be redrawn.  But it won't cause the sibling windows to be redrawn.  So whichever window you call `SetWindowPos` last will look like it's on top.