# Z- Ordering in PURE WIN32 Application

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I have a Dialog Box created using `CreateDialog()`. I have two static picture controls, one with `SS_BLACKFRAME`, and the other is a Bitmap type picture control which is set using `SendDlgItemMessage()`.

The ordering in the `.rc` file is:

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_PROMPT_RIBBON,"Static",SS_BLACKRECT,0,0,260,30
CONTROL         "",IDC_REBOOT_ICON,"Static",SS_BITMAP,10,11,10,9
```

The `IDC_REBOOT_ICON` uses an `HBITMAP`.

Everything works as expected when `IDC_PROMPT_RIBBON` is disabled.

When it is enabled, the icon is always drawn below the first control, even though it has to be drawn above it. I have tried to manually set the z-order via `SetWindowPos()` but it does not seem to do anything.

What am I missing?

What it looks like in the designer (What I am supposed to get):

[image]

What I get instead:

[image]

On stepping through the program, I can indeed confirm that the Image is being drawn first. Why is this happening?

PS. No MFC.

My Dialog Styles are

```
DS_ABSALIGN | DS_SYSMODAL | DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_3DLOOK | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
```

Comment: "the other is a Bitmap type picture control which is set using SendDlgItemMessage()" - how exactly?

Comment: Use GDI+ to load a png. Get HBITMAP and call `SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDC_REBOOT_ICON,STM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)hBitmap)`. @VuVirt .

Comment: the problem might be related to the fact that GDI+ loads a 32 bit bitmap. GDI cannot render a 32 bit bitmap and will interpret it as transparent.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` window style from your dialog.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. The 2nd child window actually is positioned *below* the 1st one in z-order: [_"If the created window is a child window, its default position is at the bottom of the Z-order."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa) (remarks). But even if you swap the order, you still have to set `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` on each child window to get reliable painting behaviour (see dupe in next comment).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Child Window Z-Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722398/child-window-z-order)

Comment: Doesn't WS_CLIPCHILDREN ignore the z ordering when drawing. I read that in another post elsewhere and made sure to have it off. Anyways, I ended up owner drawing the image and it solved all problems. If anyone can explain the exact circumstances under which this issue occured, I would be greatful! @zett42

Comment: @VuVirt why is there a PixelFormat32bppARGB value then ? Doesn't it take the 1st byte to be alpha ?

Comment: @SurajS Actually I was wrong to assume that 32 bit bitmap would cause a problem. Maybe you had to check the return value of GetHBITMAP prior to SendDlgItemMessage. Clipping and z-ordering are not the problem here anyway. I replicated your problem by loading a non-existing file and GetHBITMAP returns an error InvalidParameter in this case..

Comment: `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` isn't relevant here. This style only affects the drawing relations between parent and child. It is usually used as an optimization to reduce flickering. `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` on the other hand makes sure that siblings don't paint over each other, so what you see on the screen will be the same, regardless of the order in which the siblings are drawn.